# Is it possible to use a trusted connection (SSPI) with the SQLDMO API?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, sql-server-2000, sqldmo

I am using the DMO API via .NET to provide an alternative interface to job scheduling functionality on SQL Server 2000 Agent. The working code looks something like this:

```
using SQLDMO;

internal class TestDmo {
    public void StartJob() {
        SQLServerClass sqlServer = new SQLServerClass();
        sqlServer.Connect("MyServerName", "sql_user_id", "p@ssword"); // no trusted/SSPI overload?

        foreach (Job job in sqlServer.JobServer.Jobs) {
            if (!job.Name.Equals("MyJob")) continue;

            job.Start(null);
        }
    }
}
```

Everything works in the above-listed form (SQL Server authentication with uid/pwd provided) but I would also like to provide an option to authenticate as a trusted user (aka SSPI, Trusted Connection)

Is this possible in the DMO API? If so how?

Note: The SQLServerClass.Connect method does not seem to have any overloads, I already tried to pass null values for the user id and password to no avail and the Googles has not been helpful yet. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144581.aspx):

> object.Connect( [ ServerName ] , [ Login ] , [ Password ] )
>
> [...]
>
> Use the *Login* and *Password* arguments to specify values used for SQL Server Authentication. To use Windows Authentication for the connection, set the **LoginSecure** property to TRUE prior to calling the **Connect** method. When **LoginSecure** is TRUE, any values provided in the *Login* and *Password* arguments are ignored.

Thus, you have to set the `LoginSecure` property to `true` before calling Connect. Then, it does not matter which values you pass for the last two parameters.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Now I need to add another term to the SSPI/Trusted Connection/Integrated Security family of terms: LoginSecure

Answer (score 2):

Sure, you can use the LoginSecure property:

```
SQLServerClass sqlServer = new SQLServerClass();
sqlServer.LoginSecure = true;
sqlServer.Connect("MyServerName", null, null);
```

(actually, I don't remember if you must pas null or empty strings...)

Comment: Never mind whether you leave them null or pass empty strings. Once you set LoginSecure = true, user name and password values are ignored.

Comment: +1 Thanks for the great answer. The check mark goes Heinzi though based on timestamp. That answer landed 2 or 3 minutes earlier.

Comment: @Paul Sasik - Actually, I think you're wrong, my answer was 17:14:14 and Heinzi's 17:17:46, but no hard feelings.

Answer (score 2):

Set `SQLServerClass.LoginSecure = true` and leave user name and password null.

Have a look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms134013.aspx) for more information. I just noticed that `LoginSecure` is deprecated, though. Apparently, SQL-DMO has been superseded by SMO.

Comment: SMO is the newer, better, slicker API but its backward compatibility to MS SQL 2k is somewhat problematic. I need to use DMO so as not to burden the system with different compatibility settings etc.

Comment: @Paul Sasik: Fair enough. :-)

Comment: +1 Thanks for the great answer. The check mark goes Heinzi though based on timestamp. That answer landed 2 or 3 minutes earlier.

Comment: @Paul Sasik: Well, if you're looking at timestamps, this is what it is: Heinzi: 1-April 17:17:46; CesarGon: 1-April 17:14:55; Simon Mourier: 17:14:14. Simon was first, then I, and Heinzi was last. :-)